# How I can use refresh token in my passport JWT strategy?

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, jwt, nestjs

I am implementing a back end using nestjs, the authentication I am doing with the jwt strategy using passport-jwt. Now I have the question of how to use the refresh token, because once the user accesses with an expired token, I have to ask for another one using the refresh token. How would this be done?

This is my jwt strategy

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy){
    constructor(){
        super({
         jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
         ignoreExpiration: false,
         secretOrKey : fs.readFileSync('./src/auth/publicKey.pem')
        }
        );

    }

    async validate(payload: any){
        const user = { 
            userId: payload.sub,
            username: payload.preferred_username, 
            name: payload.name,email: 
            payload.email,
            roles: payload.realm_access.roles};

       return user;
    }
}
```